# Explain the behavior of *Rc::make_mut and why it differs compared to Mutex

Tags: rust

I needed to pass a resource between several functions which use a closure as an argument. And within these the data was handled, but it looked for that the changes that were realized to a variable will be reflected in the rest.

The first thing I thought was to use `Rc`. I had previously used `Arc` to handle the data between different threads, but since these functions aren't  running in different threads I chose `Rc` instead.

The most simplified code that I have, to show my doubts:

*The use of `RefCell` was because maybe I had to see that this syntax will not work as I expected:*

```
*Rc::make_mut(&mut rc_pref_temp)...
```

---

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    test2();
    println!("---");
    test();
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Prefe {
    name_test: RefCell<u64>,
}

impl Prefe {
    fn new() -> Prefe {
        Prefe {
            name_test: RefCell::new(3 as u64),
        }
    }
}

fn test2(){
    let mut prefe: Prefe = Prefe::new();

    let mut rc_pref = Rc::new(Mutex::new(prefe));

    println!("rc_pref Mutex: {:?}", rc_pref.lock().unwrap().name_test);

    let mut rc_pref_temp = rc_pref.clone();

    *rc_pref_temp.lock().unwrap().name_test.get_mut() += 1;

    println!("rc_pref_clone Mutex: {:?}", rc_pref_temp.lock().unwrap().name_test);

    *rc_pref_temp.lock().unwrap().name_test.get_mut() += 1;

    println!("rc_pref_clone Mutex: {:?}", rc_pref_temp.lock().unwrap().name_test);

    println!("rc_pref Mutex: {:?}", rc_pref.lock().unwrap().name_test);
}

fn test(){
    let mut prefe: Prefe = Prefe::new();

    let mut rc_pref = Rc::new(prefe);

    println!("rc_pref: {:?}", rc_pref.name_test);

    let mut rc_pref_temp = rc_pref.clone();

    *((*Rc::make_mut(&mut rc_pref_temp)).name_test).get_mut() += 1;

    println!("rc_pref_clone: {:?}", rc_pref_temp.name_test);

    *((*Rc::make_mut(&mut rc_pref_temp)).name_test).get_mut() += 1;

    println!("rc_pref_clone: {:?}", rc_pref_temp.name_test);

    println!("rc_pref: {:?}", rc_pref.name_test);
}
```

The code is simplified, the scenario where it is used is totally different. I note this to avoid comments like "you can lend a value to the function", because what interests me is to know why the cases exposed work in this way.

stdout:

```
rc_pref       Mutex  : RefCell { value: 3 }
rc_pref_clone Mutex  : RefCell { value: 4 }
rc_pref_clone Mutex  : RefCell { value: 5 }
rc_pref       Mutex  : RefCell { value: 5 }
---
rc_pref              : RefCell { value: 3 }
rc_pref_clone        : RefCell { value: 4 }
rc_pref_clone        : RefCell { value: 5 }
rc_pref              : RefCell { value: 3 }
```

### About `test()`

I'm new to Rust so I don't know if this crazy syntax is the right way.

```
*((*Rc::make_mut(&mut rc_pref_temp)).name_test).get_mut() += 1;
```

When running `test()` you can see that the previous syntax works, because it increases the value, but this increase does not affect the clones. I expected that with the use of `*Rc::make_mut(& mut rc_pref_temp)...` that the clones of a shared reference would reflect the same values.

- If `Rc` has references to the same object, why do the changes to an object not apply to the rest of the clones? Why does this work this way? Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I use `RefCell` because in some tests I thought that maybe I had something to do.

### About `test2()`

I've got it working as expected using `Mutex` with `Rc`, but I do not know if this is the correct way. I have some ideas of how `Mutex` and `Arc` works, but after using this syntax:

```
*Rc::make_mut(&mut rc_pref_temp)...
```

With the use of `Mutex` in `test2()`, I wonder if `Mutex` is not only responsible for changing the data in but also the one in charge of reflecting the changes in all the cloned references.

Do the shared references actually point to the same object? I want to think they do, but with the above code where the changes are not reflected without the use of `Mutex`, I have some doubts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to read and understand the documentation for functions you use before you use them. [`Rc::make_mut` says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.make_mut), emphasis mine:

> Makes a mutable reference into the given `Rc`.
>
> **If there are other `Rc` or `Weak` pointers to the same value, then
>   `make_mut` will invoke `clone` on the inner value to ensure unique
>   ownership. This is also referred to as clone-on-write.**
>
> See also `get_mut`, which will fail rather than cloning.

You have multiple `Rc` pointers *because you called `rc_pref.clone()`*. Thus, when you call `make_mut`, the inner value will be cloned and the `Rc` pointers will now be disassociated from each other:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let counter = Rc::new(100);
    let mut counter_clone = counter.clone();
    println!("{}", Rc::strong_count(&counter));       // 2
    println!("{}", Rc::strong_count(&counter_clone)); // 2

    *Rc::make_mut(&mut counter_clone) += 50;
    println!("{}", Rc::strong_count(&counter));       // 1
    println!("{}", Rc::strong_count(&counter_clone)); // 1

    println!("{}", counter);       // 100
    println!("{}", counter_clone); // 150
}
```

The version with the `Mutex` works because it's completely different. You aren't calling a function which clones the inner value anymore. Of course, it doesn't make sense to use a `Mutex` when you don't have threads. The single-threaded equivalent of a `Mutex` is... `RefCell`!

---

I honestly don't know how you found `Rc::make_mut`; I've never even *heard* of it before. The [module documentation for `cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html) doesn't mention it, nor does the [module documentation for `rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html).

I'd highly encourage you to take a step back and re-read through the documentation. The [second edition of The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/second-edition) has a [chapter on smart pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/second-edition/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html), including `Rc` and `RefCell`. Read the module-level documentation for [`rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html) and [`cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html) as well.

Here's what your code should look like. Note the usage of [`borrow_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut).

```
fn main() {
    let prefe = Rc::new(Prefe::new());    
    println!("prefe: {:?}", prefe.name_test);             // 3

    let prefe_clone = prefe.clone();
    *prefe_clone.name_test.borrow_mut() += 1;
    println!("prefe_clone: {:?}", prefe_clone.name_test); // 4

    *prefe_clone.name_test.borrow_mut() += 1;
    println!("prefe_clone: {:?}", prefe_clone.name_test); // 5
    println!("prefe: {:?}", prefe.name_test);             // 5
}
```

Comment: "I honestly don't know how you found Rc::make_mut;" - some people actually read the [struct docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html). They give a nice overview over available methods if you click the `[−]` on the top right. That or IDE autocomplete.

Comment: @the8472 You mean the struct docs that I linked in my first sentence and said "you really need to read what this method does before using it"? ^_^ My concern is mainly that there's some misguided resource out there that says "this is how you do it" using `make_mut` that people might follow without understanding.

Comment: I've just learned about `make_mut()` in [this article](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/11/14/Fearless-Concurrency-In-Firefox-Quantum.html) and I guess they show a great use case: in cascading style sheets, you may have a child and a parent with the same style, but if the child style is different, you use `make_mut()` to create a clone of it and you can then update the child style independently of the parent.

Comment: @antoyo haha yeah, I read that and thought about this question too . I agree that the use case we see there makes sense and might even be why the method exists in the first place. I worry now that people will see the article and be even more tempted to use it without fully understanding what the function does. I suppose we will see!