# What is the standard way to call a mutable method in a Rc-wrapped object?

Tags: rust

In the following code, I am trying to change the value of a refcounted object by calling one of its methods:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let mut x = Rc::new(Thing { num: 50 });
    x.what_to_do_to_get_mut_thing().change_num(19); //what do i do here
}

pub struct Thing {
    pub num: u32,
}

impl Thing {
    pub fn change_num(&mut self, newnum: u32) {
        self.num = newnum;
    }
}
```

I am using the `get_mut` function to achieve this, but I don't know if this is a standard way to accomplish this.

```
if let Some(val) = Rc::get_mut(&mut x) {
    val.change_num(19);
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [documentation for `Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) says:

> See the [module-level documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html) for more details.

Which has this text:

> This is difficult because [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) enforces memory safety by only giving out shared references to the value it wraps, and these don't allow direct mutation. We need to wrap the part of the value we wish to mutate in a `RefCell`, which provides *interior mutability*: a method to achieve mutability through a shared reference. [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) enforces Rust's borrowing rules at runtime.

It then demonstrates how to use it.

---

If you didn't read the API documentation, you might have instead chosen to read the entire [chapter about `Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/ch15-04-rc.html) in *The Rust Programming Language*. It has this to say:

> Via immutable references, `Rc<T>` allows you to share data between multiple parts of your program for reading only. If `Rc<T>` allowed you to have multiple mutable references too, you might violate one of the borrowing rules discussed in Chapter 4: multiple mutable borrows to the same place can cause data races and inconsistencies. But being able to mutate data is very useful! In the next section, we’ll discuss the interior mutability pattern and the `RefCell<T>` type that you can use in conjunction with an `Rc<T>` to work with this immutability restriction.

---

Applying this new knowledge to your code:

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

fn main() {
    let x = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Thing { num: 50 }));
    x.borrow_mut().change_num(19);
}
```

See also:

- [How do I share a mutable object between threads using Arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31373255/155423)
- [Situations where Cell or RefCell is the best choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30831037/155423)
- [What is the difference between Rc<RefCell<T>> and RefCell<Rc<T>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57367092/155423)
- [When I can use either Cell or RefCell, which should I choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30275982/155423)
- [Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45674479/155423)

> I am using the `get_mut` function

It's very unlikely that you want to use this.

See also:

- [Explain the behavior of *Rc::make_mut and why it differs compared to Mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44012575/155423)

Answer (score 11):

This isn't necessarily the OP's question, but a huge pitfall that can lead to issues with `Rc<RefCell<X>>` can be tracked down to the `BorrowMut` trait.

If you have run into the issue where calling `.borrow_mut()` on an `Rc<RefCell<X>>` returns another `Rc<RefCell<X>>`, make sure that the `BorrowMut` trait is not being used at the top of your script.

Rust-Analyzer automatically adds it in, and it completely changes the behavior of that function. I learned about this after many hours of debugging when I stumbled upon [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39232).

Comment: This finally was the answer as to why I just couldn't get a mutable borrow when trying to mutate under a &Rc<RefCell<T>>. I just cept on calling .borrow_mut().borrow_mut()....Thank you for commenting this

Answer (score 1):

There're now [`Rc::make_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.make_mut) and [`Arc::make_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.make_mut):

> If there are other `Rc` pointers to the same allocation, then `make_mut` will `clone` the inner value to a new allocation to ensure unique ownership. This is also referred to as clone-on-write.
>
> ```rust
> use std::rc::Rc;
>
> let mut data = Rc::new(5);
>
> *Rc::make_mut(&mut data) += 1;         // Won't clone anything
> let mut other_data = Rc::clone(&data); // Won't clone inner data
> *Rc::make_mut(&mut data) += 1;         // Clones inner data
> *Rc::make_mut(&mut data) += 1;         // Won't clone anything
> *Rc::make_mut(&mut other_data) *= 2;   // Won't clone anything
>
> // Now `data` and `other_data` point to different allocations.
> assert_eq!(*data, 8);
> assert_eq!(*other_data, 12);
> ```