# What is the difference between Rc<RefCell<T>> and RefCell<Rc<T>>?

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, interior-mutability

The Rust documentation covers `Rc<RefCell<T>>` pretty extensively but doesn't go into `RefCell<Rc<T>>`, which I am now encountering.

Do these effectively give the same result? Is there an important difference between them?

Comment: *which I am now encountering* — where are you encountering such a strange type?

Comment: @Shepmaster I see it (and then see this question) in the BOOK! I am astonished when I see it in the book. Hope I misunderstand something https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html

Comment: Ok I do know it. In that example the (uncommon) usage is correct and non replaceable.

Answer (score 87):

> Do these effectively give the same result?

They are very different.

`Rc` is a pointer with shared ownership while `RefCell` provides interior mutability. The order in which they are composed makes a big difference to how they can be used.

Usually, you compose them as `Rc<RefCell<T>>`; the whole thing is shared and each shared owner gets to mutate the contents. The effect of mutating the contents will be seen by all of the shared owners of the outer `Rc` because the inner data is shared.

You can't share a `RefCell<Rc<T>>` except by reference, so this configuration is more limited in how it can be used.  In order to mutate the inner data, you would need to mutably borrow from the outer `RefCell`, but then you'd have access to an *immutable* `Rc`. The only way to mutate it would be to replace it with a completely different `Rc`. For example:

```
let a = Rc::new(1);
let b = Rc::new(2);

let c = RefCell::new(Rc::clone(&a));
let d = RefCell::new(Rc::clone(&a));

*d.borrow_mut() = Rc::clone(&b); // this doesn't affect c
```

There is no way to mutate the values in `a` and `b`. This seems far less useful than `Rc<RefCell<T>>`.

Comment: I see. Does that mean RefCell<Rc is when you want to be able to mutate whatever Rc is pointing to?

Comment: It would be for when you have one Rc and I want to replace it with a different one. None of the clones of the original Rc would be affected.